# How does Windows decide which DNS Server to use when resolving names?

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, windows-vista

What algorithm does Windows use to decide which DNS Server it will query in order to resolve names?

Let's say I have several interfaces, all active, some with no dns server specified, some told to determine it automatically, and some with it specified manually (in interface ipv4 AND interface ipv6).

I'm asking for an answer to this general question hoping that I know how to solve a more specific problem in Windows Vista - I have two interfaces, one a lower metric and a DNS server specified manually. nslookup uses *THIS* DNS server and resolves the names correctly. However, all other applications fail to resolve the name unless I manually specify a DNS server for the other interface, which the applications then use. nslookup also uses the DNS server specified for this other interface once it is specified.

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it's determined by the NIC binding order in the Advanced Settings in the network connections folder. You can verify it by changing the binding order of the various NIC's and running nslookup as a test.

To expand on my answer, citing [the article that Evan linked](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197552(WS.10).aspx), here is an excerpt from said article:

> The DNS Client service queries the DNS servers in the following order:
>
> 1. The DNS Client service sends the name query to the first DNS server on the preferred adapter’s list of DNS servers and waits one second for a response.
> 2. If the DNS Client service does not receive a response from the first DNS server within one second, it sends the name query to the first DNS servers on all adapters that are still under consideration and waits two seconds for a response.
> 3. If the DNS Client service does not receive a response from any DNS server within two seconds, the DNS Client service sends the query to all DNS servers on all adapters that are still under consideration and waits another two seconds for a response.
> 4. If the DNS Client service still does not receive a response from any DNS server, it sends the name query to all DNS servers on all adapters that are still under consideration and waits four seconds for a response.
> 5. If it the DNS Client service does not receive a response from any DNS server, the DNS client sends the query to all DNS servers on all adapters that are still under consideration and waits eight seconds for a response.

The preferred adapter in step 1 being the adapter that's listed first in the binding order.

Comment: This process has changed in Windows 10, although i don't know the new process i know the above doesn't apply to Windows 10, see this blog -
 https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/08/14/adjusting-the-network-protocol-bindings-in-windows-10/

Comment: Archived version of Microsoft blog entry that explains the change: 2015-08-14, Kaushik Ainapure, _"Adjusting the Network Protocol Bindings in Windows 10"_, https://web.archive.org/web/20190106092511/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/08/14/adjusting-the-network-protocol-bindings-in-windows-10/

See also: related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1140216/cant-change-network-connection-priority-in-windows-10

Answer (score 37):

In Windows 10 you must update the metric of each interface in the order you want.

1. Goto Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections
2. Right click the desired connection (Higher Priority Connection)
3. Click Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4
4. Click Properties > Advanced
5. Uncheck 'Automatic Metric'
6. Enter 10 in 'Interface Metric'
7. Click OK

References:

- [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/adapter-priority-setting-unavailable-in-windows-10/d2b63caa-e77c-4b46-88b5-eeeaee00c306?auth=1)
- [Configure the Order of Network Interfaces - Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-subsystem/net-sub-interface-metric)

I used 10 for my LAN, 20 for WLAN, and 100 for VPN Interfaces (I prefer local DNS at work, this may be reverse for others). Remember [lower metric = higher priority](https://serverfault.com/a/400456/200560).

See this article in Microsoft Support for [An explanation of the Automatic Metric feature for IPv4 routes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299540/an-explanation-of-the-automatic-metric-feature-for-ipv4-routes).

I suspect this works because part of the route selection is to then set the source IP of the interface with the highest metric priority (lowest number) as you are not using the same IP address for all connections, whereas a dual-homed BGP connection would use the same source IP, but select different next-hop gateways pending destination IP.

For Server, install the DNS service and do something purposeful/intelligent, I do not agree with doing this on Server OS.

Comment: +1 For me on Windows 10, this was the only solution, thank you.

Comment: Metric modification only affects the route selection. It doesn't affect which DNS server will be used.

Comment: 14 upvotes and personal experience disagree, I agree it _shouldn't_ but the dev's at microsoft seemed to have coded it this way.

Comment: @Jruv I have one connection to an internal "isle" LAN without internet and one WIFI  internet connection active on my device. Without this solution my device first tries to resolve domains on the "isle"-DNS and when that fails (slowly) it uses the DNS from the WIFI connection. Maybe my setup gives a hint why it works for some people.

Answer (score 25):

To specifically answer the question, Windows uses the first DNS records associated with the highest ranking network interface (an `InterfaceMetric` with a lower value has higher rank).  Examples below show how to obtain and change that interface ranking value.  When there are no manual DNS servers configured on an interface, Windows relies on DNS servers provided by any DHCP server associated with a network interface.

A common scenario where this issue pops up is when you have one or more VPNs that provide a DNS server for resources defined for that virtual network.

However, the public DNS server assigned by a WiFi router is taking precedent and either claiming that hosts don't exist or are responding with the unexpected IP address.

To resolve this, we need to explicitly dictate which network interface should take precedence by specifying its associated "metric".  *(Currently, this metric appears to only be settable via PowerShell ... see below*)

## Change Metric of Network Interface (e.g., the VPN)

### First, list local interfaces and their metrics

```
C:\> Get-NetIPInterface | Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias, InterfaceMetric | Sort-Object -Property InterfaceMetric

InterfaceAlias               InterfaceMetric
--------------               ---------------
vEthernet (DockerNAT)                     15
Npcap Loopback Adapter                    25
Ethernet 11                               25
Local Area Connection* 1                  25
Local Area Connection* 2                  25
Npcap Loopback Adapter                    25
Ethernet 2                                35
Wi-Fi                                     55
Bluetooth Network Connection              65
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1               75
MY VPN                                   200   <--- There's my NIC with my fave DNS
vEthernet (Default Switch)              5000
```

### Then, set metric of network interface

**(NOTE: Make sure you do this from an administrative PowerShell console)**

```
C:\>  Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "MY VPN" -InterfaceMetric 10
```

```
C:\> Get-NetIPInterface | Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias, InterfaceMetric | Sort-Object -Property InterfaceMetric

InterfaceAlias               InterfaceMetric
--------------               ---------------
MY VPN                                    10   <--- Awesome!!! My fave DNS is now on top!!
vEthernet (DockerNAT)                     15
Npcap Loopback Adapter                    25
Ethernet 11                               25
Local Area Connection* 1                  25
Local Area Connection* 2                  25
Npcap Loopback Adapter                    25
Ethernet 2                                35
Wi-Fi                                     55
Bluetooth Network Connection              65
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1               75
vEthernet (Default Switch)              5000
```

## Testing Effect of Interface Metric

In this example, before changing the metric value, pinging a local resource that also has a publicly-defined IP returns its public IP (instead of the internal IP returned by my VPN's DNS server).

### Example When Bad!  :(

```
> ping 10640-TEST

Pinging 10640-TEST.example.com [XX.163.171.155] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from XX.163.171.155: bytes=32 time=80ms TTL=45
Reply from XX.163.171.155: bytes=32 time=76ms TTL=45
```

### Example When Good!  :)

After changing the metric on the network interface, I now see the expected internal IP address that is returned from the DNS server associated with my VPN:

```
> ping 10640-TEST

Pinging 10640-TEST.example.com [192.168.100.44] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.100.44: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.100.44: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=127
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to do this with Powershell.

Comment: Excellent answer! If someone wants to know, how the metrics are computed, here you go: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/automatic-metric-for-ipv4-routes

Comment: My research appears to confirm this answer. Up until now, like most, I assumed the Route Metric is the determining factor but it is the Interface Metric and this answer clearly shows how the process works. Well done. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You need to execute `ipconfig /flushdns` before ping.

Comment: Definitely with multiple interfaces, this is the way to go!  Great answer!

Answer (score 8):

[This page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197552(WS.10).aspx) describes the algorithm used by Windows to perform DNS queries. It's not in depth enough to give you all the answers you're looking for, but some time w/ a sniffer and this article ought to be all you need to determine what's happening in your specific situation.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem. I've spent a day trying to figure it out.

If you have several network cards and if you specify a DNS server in each of them do you know what DNS server will be used?

Well, you can check it with:

```
nslookup 192.168.3.6
```

So you see the server that your PC actually uses.

The question is: how does windows choose which DNS server to use and how can we change it.

We especially need it when we use VPN clients.

The [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/84293/214507) from [qwerty2010](https://serverfault.com/users/19152/joeqwerty) is right and correct. But you can use it ONLY when you have a NIC in control panel - network and sharing center - change adapter settings - list of nics

Only if you see the nic that is reponsible for your VPN client you can use the graphical way.

So you go Network and sharing centre -> Change adapter settings -> Advanced -> Advanced settings -> and you move *UP* the nic with DNS you'd like to USE.

However if for instance you use Shrew vpn client - you will not have any nics.

What do you do? You open registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

And you look in subfolders 0000, 0001 etc the folder with

```
DriverDesc = Shrew Soft Virtual Adapter
```

Then you copy to the clipboard

```
NetCfgInstanceId = {B498E7DE-7257-48F6-AD32-60E470030F05}
```

Now you go

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Linkage]
```

and you open `key = Bind`. You'll see the list like this

```
\Device\{1DF89CE3-CAAD-4EB7-A53F-AD16BC1D5EFD}
\Device\{70126DBE-B44D-4392-9417-0CABD6E384B1}
\Device\{D5127F8E-E7BB-4661-AE5A-A922614173D0}
\Device\{C44039AB-6801-4A9B-A736-3B12782FF411}
\Device\{85231D0F-CD05-4774-A983-632C5D83AC62}
\Device\{7E87BC81-8C58-4E05-9FA0-7897A6AA5CCE}
\Device\{3A1A3EFC-A9DE-4BCA-BAF6-81C7074487E0}
\Device\{8D41EDFC-04AC-4537-B5D5-0D54EB51A023}
```

All you have to do is put to the top

```
\Device\{B498E7DE-7257-48F6-AD32-60E470030F05}
\Device\{1DF89CE3-CAAD-4EB7-A53F-AD16BC1D5EFD}
\Device\{70126DBE-B44D-4392-9417-0CABD6E384B1}
\Device\{D5127F8E-E7BB-4661-AE5A-A922614173D0}
\Device\{C44039AB-6801-4A9B-A736-3B12782FF411}
\Device\{85231D0F-CD05-4774-A983-632C5D83AC62}
\Device\{7E87BC81-8C58-4E05-9FA0-7897A6AA5CCE}
\Device\{3A1A3EFC-A9DE-4BCA-BAF6-81C7074487E0}
\Device\{8D41EDFC-04AC-4537-B5D5-0D54EB51A023}
```

That's all. There is no need to reboot.

Now your windows will use DNS specified in shrew vpn nic when you use vpn connection.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10 and 11, DNS priority is determined by interface metric, this is documented [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190106092511/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/08/14/adjusting-the-network-protocol-bindings-in-windows-10/) - the DNS servers on the interface with the lowest metric value will be used first.

It is important to note that an interface actually has two interface metric values, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6.

You can configure these either via:

```
Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change adapter settings -> Ethernet Properties -> Internet Protocol Version 4/6 -> Advanced -> Interface Metric
```

Or via Powershell:

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceMetric 50
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -AddressFamily IPv6 -InterfaceMetric 50
```

For the purposes of DNS the lowest of the two values is considered, in other words the list of interfaces is sorted by the min(Ipv4Metric, Ipv6Metric).

Each interface (e.g. Ethernet or WiFi) then has a list of DNS servers, but within that list IPv6 servers come first.

Here is an example scenario:

| Interface | IPv4 Metric | IPv6 Metric | Min Metric | IPv6 DNS | IPv4 DNS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ethernet 1 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 2001:db8::1 | 10.1.1.1 |
| Ethernet 2 | 10 | 50 | 10 |  | 10.2.2.2 |

Windows first finds the best interface - Ethernet 2 since it has the lowest metric, and will therefore use DNS server `10.2.2.2`

The next best interface is Ethernet 1, Windows will attempt `2001:db8::1`
since IPv6 DNS servers are used first. And then finally `10.1.1.1`

Note: [See my experiments that prove this](https://github.com/jacob-pro/wsl2-dns-agent/blob/master/docs/DNS_PRIORITY.md)

Answer (score 2):

As this might help you or others, you can disable the windows round-robin usage of the listed dns to make the dns usage more predictable. Try setting the `RoundRobin=0` in the  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters` ([reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197418%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)) to disable the dns round-robing.

There is also a "timeout" for rotating the servers, you can also try to setting it to [zero](http://blog.johnruiz.com/2011/12/windows-does-not-always-honor-dns-order.html):

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters
 ServerPriorityTimeLimit=0
```

Comment: According to the mentioned "reference" (link) this applies to configure DNS server in providing multiple IP addresses for some queried FQDN in sorting order rotated from query to query. This has nothing to do with the question on how a DNS resolver (client) is choosing DNS server to be queried.

Comment: On some versions of Windows the following command line is preferred: `dnscmd /config /roundrobin 0`

Answer (score -16):

It doesn't decide randomly. You're connected to a router which gets it IP from a company which has DNS servers. They get your request unless you alter the IP manually to another DNS, for instance: [OpenDns](http://www.opendns.com/). Or perhaps you decide on having your own DNS servers. That works too. Just enter the IP adresses in the network center and all should be well. And yes, you'll have to set those manually.

You can also adjust a file in `C:\Windows\System32` called "hosts" with no extension. It allows you to have URL-requests redirected instead of being sent to the standard DNS. To a local server(which must be running and listening to port 80)

Comment: Basically everything you've said here is wrong

Comment: And an additional -1 for even mentioning the festering abomination that is the hosts file.

Comment: Way to be informative MarkM

Comment: @WebDevHobo - There's really too much to correct in a comment, but I'll touch on the big points. 1)The OP has a computer with multiple interfaces (most likely separate NICs), and each has a different DNS defined on it. In the context of the question, he is clearly running a few internal DNS servers or has a few preferred external DNS servers - the box is probably multi-homed. 2)You don't need to set an internal DNS server's address manually if you are using DHCP it in the DHCP server's configuration for that address pool. 3)The path to the hosts file is c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

Comment: And the HOSTS file shouldn't be used in this situation, or practically ever unless you are doing local development and using HOST headers or something of the like and need a FQDN to resolve locally. And the server does not need to be running port 80 whether using the HOSTS file for name resolution or a DNS server. Simply append :port_number to the end of the URL. HOSTS doesn't care about the port, just as DNS doesn't - it is a way of translating a hostname to an IP address and nothing more.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus Why don't you like the hosts file?

Comment: @Alex78191 - because it can't be properly managed by Group Policy. Reason enough.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus Regular users can't edit the hosts anyway