# How does Windows decides which DNS Server to use when resolving names and connected to a VPN

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vpn, windows-7

When connected to a VPN network how does the windows DNS client choose a prefered DNS server, between the DNS servers configured for the local connection and the server statically defined for the VPN?

I have seen the answers to ['How does Windows decides which DNS Server to use when resolving names?'](https://serverfault.com/questions/84291/how-does-windows-decides-which-dns-server-to-use-when-resolving-names) explaining that the interface metric is used to choose a preferred adapter and hence preferred DNS, however this does not seem to be the case when connected to a VPN?

Comment: Because i have manually set the interface metric of the VPN adapter to be higher than any other, yet all DNS requests are still sent to the VPNs DNS server.

Comment: Yes i have verified the metric setting. The VPN has a single statically defined server, will this always be chosen then?

Comment: So the VPN is set up to only route traffic when the interface is explicitly bound to (e.g. route/if metrics are set higher than all others) however the DNS server of the VPN is being preferred and therefore no requests can resolve straight away.

Comment: @Reaces When I view `Adapter and Bindings` as per here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-network-protocol-bindings-order#1TC=windows-7 - my VPN is bellow at the end of the list. So does it mean, that DNS defined on the VPN connection is used only for VPN specific(local) addresses?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Are you asking whether the choice of which DNS server to use for resolving a host name depends on which IP address the host name resolves to?

Comment: @kasperd Not exactly on the IP address resolved but on the domain name defined locally  - domains defined on VPN's internal DNS resolve using  that internal server, the rest uses the DNS server defined not on the VPN adapter but on the LAN adapter - but probably this is not the  way it works, but this behavior would be useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the VPN that you are using... usually, Windows resolves everything through the VPN tunnel.

Other solutions such as DirectAccess for example, let you define a [NRPT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649207(v=ws.10).aspx) to determine how a specific namespace should be resolved.