# Does a connection specific dns suffix dictate which DNS servers are queried on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system

Scenario:

- Windows 10 client machine
- Adapter #1 has subnet 192.168.1.0/24 with dns server of 192.168.1.1 and a DNS suffix of test.local
- Adapter #2 (software vpn) has subnet of 10.10.10.0/24 with dns server of 10.10.10.5 and DNS suffix of lan.company.net
- company.net is split horizon and resolves differently on the open wan as opposed to the corporate lan.
- local routing table dictates 192.168.1.1 as the default gateway

So, if the client were to query host1.local.company.net, would windows query 10.10.10.5? Maybe it would query both? If so, what would dictate the order? If it queries both simultaneously, is there a race condition here due to the split horizon config?

Thanks,
D

Comment: I believe Windows 10 uses the route metric.  See: https://serverfault.com/a/805455/20701 . Should be fairly easy to test/confirm.

Comment: Ouch, if that is true, that means you'd have to edit the interface metric for every client. That would be a rough situation.